# How do I convert this boolean expression to its DNF form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, discrete-optimization

I am having trouble converting this to its Disjunctive Normal Form.

(A ∨ ¬C ∨ D)∧ (B ∨ C ∨ ¬D) ∧(¬A ∨ B ∨ C)∧ (¬A ∨ B ∨ ¬D)

The 3 variables that exist in the brackets, is confusing me. How do the steps look like when I am trying to expand 3 variables with another 3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Let me make the notation easier by using concatenation for "and", + for "or" and ' for complementation.
So the expression is
$$X=(a+c'+d)(b+c+d')(a'+b+c)(a'+b+d')$$
Use distributivity to obtain
$$(a+c'+d)(b+c+d')=ab+ac+ad'+bc'+cc'+c'd'+bd+cd+dd'$$
and since $xx'=0$ it becomes
$$ab+ac+ad'+bc'+bd+cd+c'd'$$
Also
$$(a'+b+c)(a'+b+d')=a'+a'b+a'c+a'd'+b+bc+bd'+cd'$$
and by absorption ($x+xy=x$) it is just $a'+b+cd'$.
So again by distributivity,
$$X=(ab+ac+ad'+bc'+bd+cd+c'd')(a'+b+cd')$$
becomes
$$aa'b+ab+abcd'+aa'c+abc+acd'+aa'd'+abd'+acd'+a'bc'+bc'+bcc'd'+a'bd+bd+bcdd'+a'cd+bcd+cdd'+a'c'd'+bc'd'+cc'd'$$
and simplifies to
$$ab+abcd'+abc+abd'+acd'+a'bc'+bc'+a'bd+bd+a'cd+bcd+a'c'd'+bc'd'$$
and finally to
$$ab+acd'+bc'+bd+a'cd+a'c'd'$$

Following the comment of other user using that $X+Y=X$ iff $XY=Y$, reduce to
$$X=ab+acd'+bc'+a'cd+a'c'd'$$
since
$$(ab+bc'+a'cd)bd=(a+c'+a'c)bd$$
and
$$a+c'+a'c=a+(a+a')c'+a'c=(a+ac')+a'(c+c')=a+a'=1.$$

Comment: Good, but you can still improve it to $$ab+acd'+bc'+a'cd+a'c'd'.$$ Use, for example, that $X+Y=X$ iff $XY=Y$.